Remix Hydrogen Vercel Deployment
I successfully built a Shopify Remix Hydrogen app on a vercel project but the problem is that I am encountering This Serverless Function has crashed. error when visiting.
Upon checking on the logs I saw this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unstable_singleFetch')
I am also using Vite for this project.
